# How to search google places api using keywords?

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3

I want to build an application that allows users to search Google Places and have the data represented in a simple format like a tabular data. Say if my user type "san francisco restaurants" my application will then return a table with all restaurants in san francisco. I don't need to display maps just the names and address of restaurants. I have looked into Google Places API and this requires a latitude and longitude in its parameters. How will I get that lat. long. base on the query? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the google geocoding API (http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=san+francisco&sensor=false) to get the lat/long, but you'll have to come up with some sort of parsing methodology to get the location out of the query string ('restaurants in san francisco' vs. 'san francisco restaurants')